# Should I use a lock with the queue in Python?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, locking

I am studying multiprocessing now. I composed a code shown as following.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    while q.empty() is not True:
        filename_with_full_path = q.get()
        ...processing the file...
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = mp.Queue()

    p1 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    file_counter = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            filename_with_full_path = directory + '/' + filename
            q.put(filename_with_full_path)
            file_counter += 1

    while q.empty() is not True:
        pass  

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The thing is its working! However, everything suspiciously went well. Should I actually use locking while “put/get” methods are calling?

Comment: typo: args=(q,)

Comment: When do you want to use a `Lock`? A `Queue` internally uses a `Lock`, so most certainly not.

Comment: Thanks @Megalng !
Yes, You understood me correct! I had a hunch the Lock class has a Lock internally, but I can't found a proof.
I thought  whether to use a Lock this way or not:
`Lock.acquire
Queue.put(...) / Queue.get()...
Lock.release()`